# GCP overriding iptables rules in centOS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos7, firewall, iptables

I created a CentOS machine from base image that can be found in GCP. After powering on I looked at the iptables rule, seems like everything is on
[image]

I removed all the firewall rules and chained ones as well and created some firewall rules and saved them. When I restarted the machine all the newly created firewall rules were gone and the default ones came online. Not sure if GCP overrides firewall rules after reboot?

Comment: AFAIK, Google does not override iptables rules that you set up. My guess is that you forgot to save the rules.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. iptables and firewalls are specifically off topic. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)  or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Enabled [VPC firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/firewalls) are always enforced,** protecting your instances regardless of their configuration and operating system, even if they have not started up.